# Are there comparative studies on the parables of Vineyard from Isaiah and Matthew?

Tags: isaiah, parables, matthew

The First Reading and the Gospel Reading of Roman Catholic Holy Mass for October 8th have a parable each on the vineyard. The first one is Isaiah 5:1-7 which speaks of wild grapes that grew on good vines. In the second one from Matthew 31:33-43, Jesus speaks of the unfaithful caretakers who go to the extent of killing the son of the master. The settings of the parable from Matthew are the same as those of Isaiah. But the climaxes are different. Jesus gives a twist by including himself as a character of the parable, which was not there in Isaiah.

Are there any comparative studies involving the parables of the vineyard, as presented in Isaiah and Matthew? Inputs from scholars of any denomination are welcome.

Comment: Did you mean Isaiah in the title?

Comment: Thanks, FAMI. The question stands edited.